# Compression in Hadoop Sequence File

Tags: filesystems, compression, hadoop, sequence, hdfs

I have some basic questions about the hadoop sequential file.

1) To what extent the default compression codec compresses the file?

2) I have hadoop sequence file of 100 MB when i read this file and dump its content to text file size of text file i observed is around 1GB(Is it Ok?)

3)While reading the sequence file what is the significance of **"syncSeen()" and 
"seek(long position)"** ? Is there any problem if i do not use these calls while reading?
any example on how to use these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SequenceFile.Reader#seek](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.Reader.html#seek%28long%29) will position the reader at the given point in the SequenceFile.

According to the [Hadoop:The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do)

> A sync point is a point in the stream that can be used to resynchronize with a record boundary if the reader is “lost”—for example, after seeking to an arbitrary position in the stream. Sync points are recorded by SequenceFile.Writer, which inserts a special entry to mark the sync point every few records as a sequence file is being written. Such entries are small enough to incur only a modest storage overhead—less than 1%. Sync points always align with record boundaries.

[SequenceFile.Reader#syncseen](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile.Reader.html#syncSeen%28%29) will tell if a sync mark has been passed while reading a SequenceFile.

Comment: Is it neccessary to use syncseen while reading the hadoop sequence file? What issues we may face if we dont use it?

Comment: I'm curious about how records can be aligned to block boundaries, which is the most important thing to me. Is there a mechanism to do ensure this?